# InstallShield battery level warning

Tags: installation, windows-installer, installshield, power-management

Is there any way to display an warning message if the user tries to install my app when the battery level is under 5%? I'm using InstallShield.

Comment: +1 For being very thoughtful about your users... these days, that's very rare.

Comment: +1 nice idea. i love this suggestion. but now, InstallShield does not have this feature.

Comment: Why would that be useful? I have working standby and hibernate both of which so far failed to disrupt any installation.

Comment: a warning would not be bad anyway

Comment: Isn't this available? If not, I think it should qualify as something that should be a standard Windows Installer action. Perhaps we can ask the Wix guys to add it as a standard launch condition in Wix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know if Installshield supports this directly, but you could create a autorun menu program that gets run first, that checks battery level, then if its ok, runs setup ?

Answer (score 1):

There are several .NET-related answers in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/681717/how-do-you-get-the-current-battery-level-in-net-cf-3-5). At least the [GetSystemPowerStatusEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa457088.aspx) function could be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

What version, edition of InstallShield and project type are you using?   The answer depends, but generally InstallShield can call Win32, COM and Managed API's so it is very doable with a little bit of coding.

I'd wonder if you really want to check at 5% though.  Most installs I've seen simply check that you are on line power instead of battery when gating the install.  5% is already pretty low and might now give you much time to do whatever you need.