# Linking code to Pc hardware (battery percentage/ charging etc)

Tags: c, hardware, libraries, batterylevel

I was hoping to build a program that needs access to battery percentage and to know weather its plugged in (charging) or not, im new to C and have only coded using the command line, is there any library that has this system or information, or would i need to learn another language?

i tried the following code but had no luck:

```
if (strcmp("BatteryLevel", commandArgv[0]) == 0) {

                printf("The battery level is ",);
                return 1;
        }
```

And if its possible where or how can i learn these things, as i couldn't find books that offer learning between basic c programming and professional programming?

Comment: What OS will this run on? If it's for Windows, I suggest looking into WMI.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/681717/how-do-you-get-the-current-battery-level-in-net-cf-3-5