# Check battery status in Windows Mobile 6.5

Tags: vb.net, windows-mobile-6.5

I am working on VB.NET windows mobile application, in visual studio 2005. 
I want to check my device battery charge so I given code my form load like this:

```
Imports System.IO 
Imports System.Data 
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging 
Imports System.Configuration 
Imports Microsoft.Win32 
Imports System.Windows.Forms 
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic 
Imports System 

Dim power As SystemInformation.PowerStatus = SystemInformation.PowerStatus
Dim percent As Single = power.BatteryLifePercent
MsgBox("Percent battery life remaining: " & percent * 100)
```

But showing error

> SystemInformation.PowerStatus  is not defined.

Any one tell me how I can resolve this issue

Comment: Visual Studio **2005**?  Do you mean *2015*?  Do you have a reference to `System.Windows.Forms` in your project?  And the appropriate `Imports` statement?

Comment: yes sir,i wam working in visual studio 2005. Imports System.io
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging
Imports System.Configuration
Imports Microsoft.Win32
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports system

Comment: i added this much imports

Comment: dear @tim sir ,any idea what i can do?

Comment: any one have any idea? how i can resolve this issue..

Answer (score 0):

Forget the guys talking about VS2015. This is not related to compact framwework running on your windows mobile device!

you need to use the state and notification api: in c# this is

```
using Microsoft.WindowsMobile.Status; // see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsmobile.status.aspx
...
BatteryLevel batteryLevel = SystemState.PowerBatteryStrength;
BatteryState batteryState = SystemState.PowerBatteryState;
```

ensure you are on target Windows Mobile 6.x! and comapct framework 3.5

Another approach would be to use P/Invoke and GetSystemPowerStatusEx.
see [How do you get the current battery level in .NET CF 3.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/681717/how-do-you-get-the-current-battery-level-in-net-cf-3-5)

If you do not install and target at least the [Windows Mobile 6 SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6135) you will not see Microsoft.WindowsMobile.Status in add References.

If you want to stay with PPC2003, you need to use the P/Invoke for GetSystemPowerStatusEx.

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28886/Windows-Mobile-Power-Management) is a nice artcile about getting Battery Status, if you understand this. There are many other sites, don't be lazy and use your internet search engine.

And sorry, but as MS renames there SDKs and re-arranges web sites without looking at existing links, even on there pages and search results, I was unable to find the Developer Toolkit (DTK) for Windows Mobile 6.5 (which has been renamed to Windows Embedded Handheld 6.5).

Comment: i am not able to download Microsoft.WindowsMobile.Status ..without adding this into refernce i cannot import this right?

Comment: sir i can able to see Target device :Pocket PC 2003 SE Emulator

Comment: PocketPC 2003 is very outdated and does not have WindowsMobile.Status. Please install at least Windows Mobile 6 SDK or use pinvoke with the native function GetSystemPowerStatusEx

Answer (score -1):

`PowerStatus` when used to declare the type of a variable part of `System.Windows.Forms`, not `SystemInformation`. The line

`Dim power As SystemInformation.PowerStatus = SystemInformation.PowerStatus`

needs to be changed to:

`Dim power As System.Windows.Forms.PowerStatus = SystemInformation.PowerStatus`

This worked for me (I'm in Visual Studio 2013, but that shouldn't make a difference).

```
Private Sub ShowBatteryPercent()
    Dim power As System.Windows.Forms.PowerStatus = SystemInformation.PowerStatus
    Dim percent As Single = power.BatteryLifePercent
    MsgBox("Percent battery life remaining: " & percent * 100)
End Sub
```

Must make sure you have `Imports System.Windows.Forms`.

Comment: sir i have Imports System.Windows.Forms but while using this code i am getting error System.Windows.Forms.PowerStatus is not defined

Comment: i am working on visual studio 2005 and developing application for widnows mobile device center,i want to show battery status of device

Comment: I don't believe the version of visual studio should matter. Do you have `System.Windows.Forms` listed in your project references also? What version of .NET framework are you developing for?

Comment: sir i can able to see Target device :Pocket PC 2003 SE Emulator

Comment: In Visual studio 2005 i think .net frame work 2 is using

Comment: this answer is not suitable for COMPACT FRAMEWORK